# Can we allow our app user to add geofencing radius in android app?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-android-api-2, android-geofence

I want to create an application that tracks childs location through firebase and implement geofence on that location. How do i initiate GeofenceClient with that location from firebase instead of my own location?

I have created an app that is fetching location from database of other user which is in latitude and logitude and can be converted to latlng datatype. I have also created feature of geofencing but heres the problem : This geofence check my location for geofence(i suppose this is happening because i have intiated geofence Client as     //geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);)

What should i do to pass the location of other user that i fetched from firebase in form of latitude and longitude in this geofencingClient.

Comment: Sounds like a 3 step process: 1) load the local from Firebase, 2) pass that to your Geofencing client, 3) ....  OK, so maybe it's a 2 step process.  --- If you've done each of these steps separately, but are struggling to make them work together, please edit your question to [show the minimal-but-complete of where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's helpful).

Comment: what i have done currently: My app creates geofence and monitors my device location|||--What i want to do is: Execute geofence events on another devices location that i have fetched from firebase|||-- To execute geofencing on my own location i used this line//geofencingClient=LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);) in following line (this) in geofencing Client tells on what location geofencing is to be implemented |||--To execute geofencing on (location in form of coordinates)that i retrieving from firebase how should i initialize geofencingClient